# Multi plot and overlay graphs for two dataframes using ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data that I use to create two data frames:

```
#Event csv
timestamp,event
2013-04-03 22:59:05.061Z,A
2013-04-03 22:59:05.061Z,B
2013-04-03 22:59:07.109Z,C
2013-04-03 22:59:07.115Z,D
2013-04-03 22:59:07.209Z,E


# Performance data
hostname;interval;timestamp;CPU;user;nice;system;iowait;steal;idle
box1;1;2013-04-03 22:59:02 UTC;-1;10.53;0.00;2.01;0.50;0.00;86.97
box1;1;2013-04-03 22:59:03 UTC;-1;0.25;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;99.75
box1;1;2013-04-03 22:59:04 UTC;-1;0.00;0.00;0.25;0.25;0.00;99.50
box1;1;2013-04-03 22:59:05 UTC;-1;10.72;0.00;1.00;0.25;0.00;88.03
box1;1;2013-04-03 22:59:06 UTC;-1;10.67;0.00;10.67;0.00;0.25;78.41
box1;1;2013-04-03 22:59:07 UTC;-1;5.01;0.00;9.02;3.51;0.00;82.46
box1;1;2013-04-03 22:59:08 UTC;-1;12.28;0.00;11.53;4.26;0.25;71.68
box1;1;2013-04-03 22:59:09 UTC;-1;15.88;0.00;11.66;10.92;0.50;61.04
```

Now I am trying to plot these two dataframes using ggplot by overlaying data from events over performance data.

```
# This works
perfomance <- read.csv("performance.csv", header=TRUE,sep=";")
perfomance$timestamp <- as.POSIXlt(perfomance$timestamp)
p <- ggplot(data=performance, aes(x=timestamp, y=idle)) + geom_line()
```

Which produces

[image: Graph of cpu idle over time]

Now, getting to overlay the events data is problematic. Here's what I have tried

```
> p + geom_point(data=events, aes(colour=factor(event)))
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'idle' not found

> p + geom_point(data=events, aes(colour=factor(event)), inherit.aes = FALSE)
Error: geom_point requires the following missing aesthetics: x, y

> p + geom_point(data=events, aes(x=timestamp, colour=factor(event)), inherit.aes = FALSE)
Error: geom_point requires the following missing aesthetics: y
```

How can I get some markers on the graph that show the events as an overlay? I don't care about their Y coordinate. I need them to be visible.

Comment: For the data frame `events` what is `ggplot` supposed to use as a y value for each point? Because you haven't supplied any, it's assuming it's going to use the same variable as from the other data frame, `idle`, and that variable doesn't exist in `events`.

Comment: Maybe this (not tested) : `p + geom_point(data=events, aes(colour=factor(event),x=timestamp,y=25))` ?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no Y value in the supplied csv. The event column just says at timestamp 1, we did action X on some program, at timestamp2, we did action Y... Is there a way to plot something at the X value (a vertical line perhaps?) Or should I attempt to merge the two data frames into one?

Comment: Lots of options. juba suggested simply setting a single y value for each one. Or you could use `geom_vline` (remember that it expects `xintercept` not `x` aesthetic). Or merging, but that seems the most complicated to me.

Comment: @Juba: Your solution works... Though, is it possible to get the y coordinate of the point to be intelligently placed by R instead of hard coded to 25?

Comment: @Joran: This is almost there: p + geom_vline(xintercept=as.numeric(events$timestamp), linetype=4, aes(colour=factor(event)) ) What am I missing to add a legend and colour to each vline?

Comment: Try mapping `xintercept` inside of `aes` as well.

Comment: Joran, Yup! that works. Do you want to compose an answer? I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this using `geom_vline`:

```
p + geom_vline(linetype=4, aes(colour=factor(event),xintercept = timestamp) )
```

Comment: Also blogged about your solution: http://andorian.blogspot.com/2013/04/vertical-line-markers-in-r-using.html